# Necessary files for xcode project doesn's show

Tags: xcode

I want to add font in my project and i've seen a lot of tutorials how to do it, they say that I need file called infoplist but my xcode doesnt really show that file

[image]

that's what I get after creating a new project
btw im using xcode 13 beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of a change to Xcode 13 - the `Info.plist`, which used to be generated by default by Xcode app templates, is now only created when needed.

If you click on the top level item in your project tree (the `asd` with the blue Xcode item) the main editing window will show your app details and a list of targets – the item(s) that will be compiled from your source.

Click on the target representing your app, and you'll see it has an `Info` tab. Any changes a tutorial told you to make to `Info.plist` can be made in there.

Making changes does seem to add an `info` file into the project navigator view, but it only contains the customisations you make, rather than all the settings as with previous version of Xcode.